# Looking for correction on my sentences made using the ます conjugation!

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, sentence

田中さんは言いません。Tanaka didn't say anything.

田中さんは私を語ません。Tanaka doesn't speak of me.

明さんは笑いました。 Akira laughed.

明さんは家を作ました。 Akira built a house.

中校に学びませんでした。 I didn't learn in middle school.

田中さんは明さんが見ませんでした。Tanaka didn't see Akira.

These are the sentences I wrote using the ます conjugation but I don't know if they're correct or understandable... Please correct them if necessary!

I'm looking to form basic sentences for story telling as I'd like to write stories in Japanese! I apologize if my aim is not clear!

Comment: Perhaps you could add what you want to express with these.  You seem to be handling the ます form fine.  But your first two sentences sound a bit odd without context:  (1) Tanaka doesn't say.  (2) Tanaka doesn't speak me.  If you explain what you meant to say, we could certainly help you there.  Your last sentence sounds a bit like you're saying As for Tanaka, Akira didn't see him.

Comment: @A.Ellett I put what I meant in my question! I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @istrasci Hmmm... I wasn't thinking about the proofreading aspect of our guidelines when moving forward with an answer here.  My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have mastered the ます form.  Generally, this form isn't used to tell a story, particularly if it is written.

I don't know where you are in your study of Japanese.  But these are good attempts on your part.

Now let's look at each of your sentences:

> 田中さんは言いません。Tanaka didn't say anything.

You need to add something for "anything" in the sentence.

> 田中さんは何も言いませんでした。

For

> 田中さんは私を語ません。Tanaka doesn't speak of me.

Generally you're going to use the structure ...のことを to express the idea of talking about "...".

> 田中さんは私のことは何も話しません。

For

> 明さんは笑いました。 Akira laughed.

You nailed this one.

For

> 明さんは家を作りました。 Akira built a house.

This good stab.  However, 作りました means "made".  Use
建てました to say "built".

For

> 中校に学びませんでした。 I didn't learn in middle school.

Two points,中校 should be 中学校
Also, there's a distinction made between に and で.  Generally, に expresses where something is; で expresses where something happens.

You sentence sounds like you're saying, "I didn't study in middle school".

Instead try:

> 中学校で何も習いませんでした。

For

> 田中さんは明さんが見ませんでした。Tanaka didn't see Akira.

you need to indicate that Akira is who is being seen.  You express this by using を

> 田中さんは明を見ませんでした

---

If you're telling a story, you generally will use the plain form.  So, these sentences would look something the following:

> 田中さんは何も言わなかった。田中さんは私のことを何も話さない。　　明は笑った。田中さんは家を建てた。中学校で何も習わなかった。田中さんは明を見なかった。

However, depending on where you are in your study, these forms might look a odd to you.  They're not that hard to learn though.

Comment: Would you mind if I asked what form is used for storytelling?

Comment: @Eden I changed my mind about 話す vs いう.

Comment: Also note that it should have been 作りました rather than 作ました

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you.  I'd missed that.  Copied and pasted too quickly.